# .ics emails blocked for one user

Tags: email, exchange, calendar, ics

We have one user who doesn't receive any emails with .ics files attached (external calendar invites). According to Exchange the emails are delivered however they never show up in the Inbox, or Junkmail (and are not blocked on the spam filter).

We are running Exchange 2007.

The user has a MacBook Pro running Mail (OS X Lion), an iPad and iPhone. (All have the Exchange account and none receive external invitations).

Everyone else in the organization is able to receive these emails.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the only Mac user? What `Spam Filter` or AV is used, check if there is settings within the Mail Scanner part of the software for stripping out attachments by extension/type.

Answer (score 0):

The problem likely lies with iCloud, which seems to take issue with non-iCloud-server-based events. I hadn't heard of .ics invites not showing up at all, but after I upgraded to Lion, I wasn't able to add them to my iCal on any device until I turned off cloud syncing (Settings > General > iCloud > Calendars ), and switched to iTunes calendar sync. Definitely a clunkier sync, but it should allow your user to view and open .ics invites.